# ExtJS : Which event fires after Treepanel selectionChange?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I want to force the RootNode selection in ExtJS TreePanel, then I do some operation in the the selectionchange event of treepanel. After that I want to get the selected rows from the treepanel and pass it as an event parameter. I'm able to achieve it with the given code, but sometimes 'selModel.getSelection()' not getting all the selected rows. Probably before completing selectionchange event it is excecuting the next line.

```
var tree = this.getTree();
var selModel = tree.getSelectionModel();
selModel.select(tree.getRootNode()); // fires selectionchange event

var selectedRows = selModel.getSelection(); 
if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
//Here I fire another event by passing selectedRows as parameter
}

selectionchange: function(){
//some looping operation
}
```

Would be great if anyone can help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you are invoking this code: `selModel.select(tree.getRootNode());`

Wouldn't be more efficient to do

Replace this:

```
var tree = this.getTree();
var selModel = tree.getSelectionModel();
selModel.select(tree.getRootNode()); // fires selectionchange event

var selectedRows = selModel.getSelection(); 
if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
//Here I fire another event by passing selectedRows as parameter
}

selectionchange: function(){
//some looping operation
}
```

And make this:

```
var tree = this.getTree();
var selectedRows= tree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();//This line grab all selected items by user.
//rest code the same
if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
//Here I fire another event by passing selectedRows as parameter
}
```

Comment: I want to select the rootnode by default on load of the treepanel, I'm able to do this using 'selModel.select(tree.getRootNode());' also there are some operation inside the selection change event.

Comment: If i understood correctly code `selectionchange: function(){}` is invoked first . Then code `if (selectedRows.length > 0)` second ?

Comment: And you mean on load = load from store ?

Comment: I think there is a problem with asynchronously calling. Did you try to invoke this code: `var selectedRows = selModel.getSelection(); if (selectedRows.length > 0) {}` in `selectionchange` function ?

Comment: In the documentation you can see that `selection` is a parameter for this function.